# Sensitive instrument 5 V needed

Tags: dc-dc-converter, backlight

I need advice on powering a STN-display module. I am confused on getting the correct power source for the backlight.

The backlight of old module (SP12N002) contained CCFL and new (SP12N01L6ALCZ) is LED. The input voltage for driving the old CCFL circuit was 12V (inverter INVC828 for LMD7420PLFC-X). The new LED display module needs  5V/84mA. Should I use a simple DC-DC convertor (IL1205S)? Otherwise, I was also wondering if I can take a simple DC power supply (mobile phone charger with 5V/500mA) and power it.

Many thanks for your help.

[image: specs]

PS: A DC-DC convertor from the company exists with circuit diagram here: https://www.koe-europe.com/doc/AN13005-upgrading-CCFL-to-LED.pdf

Comment: You could probably get a buck converter to 8V and use a 7805 to go down to 5V.

Answer (score 2):

If your normal 5V power supply has enough "drive" to cope with the extra 84 mA LED current then just use that. You need 5V for the logic according to your data sheet picture so check that option out first.

You don't *have* to use a DC-to-DC converter - they usually provide an isolated output and this isn't needed.